# SMS Personalization

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

In Contact Builder, I have table xxx joined to the MobileConnect Demographics table.  When I send an SMS, I can include `%%fieldname%%` in the text and have the corresponding value correctly populate in the text - but only when I choose fieldnames from the Mobile Connect Demographics table.  How do I include personalization in the SMS when the fieldname is from table xxx ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending to a list, the only options for personalization strings,`%%fieldname%%`, are attributes within the MobileConnect Demographics table.

If you are doing a [SendtoDE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_data_extension_sends.htm&type=5) you can use any field in the sending DE as a personalization string. You can also use the new [Content Builder Send Preview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_ceb_subscriber_preview.htm&type=5) option with this send flow for mobile messages

Another option would be to use a `lookup()` function to the DE that contains the value you want.